# How do I change cell padding in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services

Once my report is built, how do I change the cell padding of all cells? Is there a way to do this all at once? If not, can I change the default values for cell padding so I don't have this issue on my next report?

SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Builder 3.0

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you have your properties window already displayed on your report builder screen (View -> Properties Window), then select all the text boxes (make sure they are just text boxes) and go to the properties viewer.

Towards the top (you may need to scroll up) will be padding.

You may enter anything you wish here in the following syntax: `Lpt, Rpt, Tpt, Bpt`, or you can expand that section to enter the individual values.

If you want 0 padding for the cells you can enter: `0pt, 0pt, 0pt, 0pt`.

Comment: I realize this is a little late in trying to help you, Robert, but I hope it provides answers for anyone else trying to do the same thing.